# コンソールで git コマンドの操作時に Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: と表示されてしまう

Tags: git

ssh でのリモート接続したコンソール環境にて、`git clone` などを実行すると以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。
どのように対応すればよいでしょうか。

```
(gnome-ssh-askpass:6555): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: XXX.XXX.YYY.ZZZ:0.0
```

なお、対象のリモートリポジトリはアクセス認証が必要なオンプレの Git サーバになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パスワード入力で GUI が必要な `gnome-ssh-askpass` を起動しようとしてエラーになっています。
環境変数 `SSH_ASKPASS` の値を `unsetenv` で未定義にしてみてください。

**設定状況を確認**

```
$ printenv SSH_ASKPASS
/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
```

**unsetenv で未定義にする**

```
$ unsetenv SSH_ASKPASS
```

---

**参考**
[コンソール越しに git コマンドから Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display と怒られた時 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ma2saka/items/0c948a5bc13581c251f7)
[Prevent git from popping up gnome password box - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21422782)